# Problem with parse error in matlab - Can't import data from .txt

Tags: matlab, parsing, octave

I have a question and I'd appreciate some help.

```
    temp = importdata('teste.txt');
for i= 1:size(temp.texdata,1)
    for j= 1:size(temp.texdata,2)
        if i== 1 || j <= 2   %copy alphanumeric data of 1º row and columns 1 and 2
            dados{i,j} = temp.texdata{i,j};
        elseif j-2<= size(temp.data,2)  %copy numeric data for the remain cells
            dados{i,j} = temp.data(i-1,j-2);
        end
    end
end
```

error: matrix cannot be indexed with .
error: parse error
error: called from
    C:/......../1º Semestre/IP/projeto_2.0.m at line 134 column 1

It appears the error on top cause I wrote on my code.

My code must import data from a very big txt file that I have.
Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem

Comment: it would be helpful if you supply a short text file so we know better what you are dealing with

Answer (score 0):

When you import the data, `temp` is a matrix, not a struct.

Attempting to access a field as if it where a struct results in the error you observe